# Is there an something wrong with the value being returned to this function in MATLAB resulting in an incorrect answer?

Tags: matlab

My code below should return a `max_flow` value of 7 for the given network but it returns 2. I am certain my error is confined to generating the paths from `s` to `t` as I have  re-wriiten the program in c++ which I have more experience in. I have also printed out my residual graph to see whats going on  which is obviously also incorrect.
There shouldn't be negative integers within it for one thing.

```
 0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0    -2     2
 0     0     0     2     0     6
 0     0     0    -2    -6     0
```

I have also verified its 7 by hand. Inside my main function in c++ I have used  `while (int sent = dfs(s, t, INF))` as the condition for my while loop but in MATLAB I figured the equivalent was
`while  sent == dfs(s,t,INF)`. I think that this could be the problem but I cant find an alternative and don't know where the hole in my logic is. I know that MATLAB has a built in `maxlow` function but I wanted to build my own as a learning experience.
I am using a depth first search to find paths from source to sink in my residual graph `Flow`.
I would appreciate any pointers to mending this and also anything else you think should/could be improved

```
    function ff
    clear;

%adjacency matrix representing capacities


    Cap =  [0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0;
            0, 0, 2, 1, 4, 0;
            0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0;
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2;
            0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6;
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
                            ];




    len = length(Cap)

    Flow =zeros([len,len])
     
   
    
% source and sink
 INF=99999;
 s = 1; 
 t = 6; 
 max_flow=0;
 
 sent = 0;
 
 visited=boolean(zeros(1,len));
 
   sent = dfs(s,t,INF);

   while  sent == dfs(s,t,INF)
       
       max_flow =+ sent;

       visited=boolean(zeros(1,len));
      
   end
  
  disp('Residual graph:');
  disp(Flow);
  disp(['Max flow is ' num2str(max_flow)]);


%%dfs


    function F= dfs(Source,Sink,minimum)
      
       
      
     visited(Source) = true;
     
      
       if Source==Sink
          F = minimum;
        end 
 
       for  i = drange (2:length(visited))
            flow_cap = Cap(Source,i) - Flow(Source,i);
            
           

            if visited(i)==false && flow_cap > 0
                 visited(i) = true
             
            

                  if sent == dfs(i,Sink,min(minimum,flow_cap))
                     Flow(Source,i) =  Flow(Source,i)+sent;
                     Flow(i,Source) = Flow(i,Source)-sent ;
                     F=sent;
                  
                  end

          
           end

         F=sent;
         
        end
       
   end
  
end
```

Comment: Note that `while (int sent = dfs(s, t, INF))` and `while  sent == dfs(s,t,INF)` are not equivalent. The first will continue as long as `sent` is non-zero, and update `sent` each iteration. The second will compare the value of `sent` to the output of `dfs`. You while loop in MATLAB will never if it even starts, as `s,t, sent` are never updated. within the loop, so the condition does not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Ander Biguri said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71742583/is-there-an-something-wrong-with-the-value-being-returned-to-this-function-in-ma#comment126796305_71742583), `sent == …` doesn’t update `sent` like you do in C++. You cannot update a variable inside an expression (AFAIK). In MATLAB you’d update `sent` inside the loop.

Also, `max_flow =+ sent` is not the equivalent of `max_flow += sent` in C++. You are applying the unwary `+` to `sent`, which does nothing, then assigning the result to `max_flow`. That is, you are doing `max_flow = +sent`.

This would be a correct loop in MATLAB:

```matlab
sent = dfs(s,t,INF);
while sent
   max_flow += sent;
   visited = zeros(1,len,'logical');
   sent = dfs(s,t,INF);
end
```

Finally, sharing `visited` with the `dfs` function is bad practice. You should try to use only local variables everywhere. You can pass the array into the function and then return it again, for example `[sent,visited] = dfs(s,t,INF,visited)`.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked your code, but why not simply use MATLAB's own [`maxflow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.maxflow.html) function?

```
>> Cap =  [0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0;
           0, 0, 2, 1, 4, 0;
           0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0;
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2;
           0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6;
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
                           ];
>> g = digraph(Cap)
g =
  digraph with properties:

    Edges: [9x2 table]
    Nodes: [6x0 table]
>> maxflow(g,1,6)
ans =
     7
```

This gives the answer 7 as you expected.

Comment: Hi, yeah Im aware I could of used that but MATLABS's version uses a BFS to find the augmenting paths  and Im trying to implement a DFS for this part.